# How to delete a particular instance of FileSystemWatcher object

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, windows

I have a windows application which uses FileSystemWatcher to monitor the change of files. Multiple file locations can be added and for each location a new instance of FileSystemWatcher is created and the location is added to a listbox. There is an option to delete a location from the listbox. I need to delete/dispose the particular instance of FileSystemWatcher when a location is deleted. Is there any way to attain this? Thanks in advance.

```
FileSystemWatcher fsw;

    private void CreateFWInstance(string strLoc)
    {
        if (strLoc != string.Empty)
        {
            fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

            fsw.Path = strLoc;
            fsw.SynchronizingObject = this;

            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you'll need to keep a reference to the instance, e.g. as the *value* in the list box entry, or perhaps a `Dictionary<string, FileSystemWatcher>` to map from path to watcher. Then just dispose of the watcher and remove it from the dictionary / remove the list item.

Comment: how can i dispose the object instance? I tried removing the item from dictionary, but the location is still being watched.

Comment: Call Dispose on it - it's as simple as that! (Setting EnableRaisingEvents should work too, but you should dispose it anyway.)